# How to find rows of a dataframe containing a date value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a huge **dataframe** containing multiple data types in different columns. I want to find rows that contain date values in different columns.
Here a test **dataframe**:

```
   dt = pd.Series(['abc', datetime.now(), 12, '', None, np.nan, '2020-05-05'])
   dt1 = pd.Series([3, datetime.now(), 'sam', '', np.nan, 'abc-123', '2020-05-25'])
   dt3 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
   df = pd.DataFrame({"A":dt.values, "B":dt1.values, "C":dt3.values})
```

Now, I want to create a **new dataframe** that contains only dates in both columns A and B, here rows 2nd and last.
Expected output:

```
                            A                           B  C
1  2020-06-01 16:58:17.274311  2020-06-01 17:13:20.391394  2
6                  2020-05-05                  2020-05-25  7
```

What is the best way to do that? Thanks.

P.S.> Dates can be in any standard format.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: Date values means, ``string`` values or ``datetime`` objects

Comment: can be both datatypes @Sushanth

Comment: Is necessary test all columns? Or only columns `A,B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df[['A', 'B']].transform(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').isna().any(axis=1)   
df = df[~m]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
                            A                           B  C
1  2020-06-01 17:54:16.377722  2020-06-01 17:54:16.378432  2
6                  2020-05-05                  2020-05-25  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for test only `A,B` columns is [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for not match any non datetimes:

```
df = df[df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').notna().all(axis=1)]

print (df)
                            A                           B  C
1  2020-06-01 16:14:35.020855  2020-06-01 16:14:35.021855  2
6                  2020-05-05                  2020-05-25  7
```

Comment: Your second solution is related to my case. But, to check dates in both columns, I think df.all should be used instead of df.any with df.notna method. That'd be the exact answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dt = pd.Series(['abc', datetime.now(), 12, '', None, np.nan, '2020-05-05'])
dt1 = pd.Series([3, datetime.now(), 'sam', '', np.nan, 'abc-123', '2020-05-25'])
dt3 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":dt.values, "B":dt1.values, "C":dt3.values})

m = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df['A'], errors='coerce'),
               pd.to_datetime(df['B'], errors='coerce')], axis=1).isna().all(axis=1)

print(df[~m])
```

Prints:

```
                            A                           B  C
1  2020-06-01 12:17:51.320286  2020-06-01 12:17:51.320826  2
6                  2020-05-05                  2020-05-25  7
```